# conversion JSONObject from string

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I am currently working on project which requires json parsing in Android.. I am getting json from php page but somehow JSONObject is not able to convert data String to JSONObject.

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String data=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

the data I'm getting is

```
   {"success":"1"}
    <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
    <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

how should I handle this so that I don't get the JSONObject exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use org.json.JSONObject

example:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
...
String data = data.split("<!--")[0];
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
```

Comment: yes ... i did that .. but it gives exception due to <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
    <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: Why don't you strip rest of data?

Comment: how ?? that is wat i am asking for??

Comment: thanks for the regular expression.. but i was looking for a more abstract method.. because data String is containing source code.. so every time this wont work

Comment: Can you give a usecase of what you're saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58278/discussion-between-user3760881-and-pankaj-sharma).